# How to parse observable to string in angular

Tags: angular, string, observable

I have script like this :

```
getLastStatus(id): Observable<string>{
    let url_detail = this.apiurl + `/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<any>(url_detail).pipe(
        map(data=>{
            var status = data.reduce((item, curr) => {
                return item.id < curr.id ? curr : item;
              }).status.title;
        
            return status;
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

I want to return string, then I changed script toString like this :

```
getLastStatus(id): Observable<string>{
    let url_detail = this.apiurl + `/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<any>(url_detail).pipe(
        map(data=>{
            var status = data.reduce((item, curr) => {
                return item.id < curr.id ? curr : item;
              }).status.title;
        
            return status;
        }).toString,
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

But shows error :

```
Argument of type '() => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<any, unknown>'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Observable<unknown>'
```

What should i fix from my script so that the return string is not observable?

Then I can call it with a function like this :

```
console.log(this.service.getLastStatus(1));
```

Please help.

Comment: you can not, when you has an Observable **always need subscribe**. in subscription function you get the value. Think that you're calling an async function, you don't know when the function has finished

Comment: yes, I have got a solution for this. Thanks!